# Stringtemplate-4: using '@' as a custom delimiter

Tags: java, stringtemplate-4

When using StringTemplate 4.0.2 the following object construction:

```
ST st = new ST("@myToken@", '@', '@');
```

produces the exception:

```
1:8: '@' came as a complete surprise to me
Exception in thread "main" org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.STException
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.Compiler.reportMessageAndThrowSTException(Compiler.java:213)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:143)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroup.compile(STGroup.java:427)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.<init>(ST.java:142)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.<init>(ST.java:136)
```

Is there some special way to use the '@' character as a custom delimiter or is it simply not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ is used for defining regions and is a reserved operator.

Comment: It might be an idea to throw an exception when calling the constructor with '@' as delimiter. It took me quite a while to find out this was the reason it wasn't working.